# Old Java Application -> setLookAndFeel(swing.WindowsClassic), is there a java.awt variant

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

I have an old java application and the GUI did not work 100% with Windows7, especially if Windows AERO Effects are active. I fixed the problem for all java.swing GUI Elements by setting `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel")`

But the application contains one Error Dialog Class `JMessageBox` which only imports

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

And always when a dialog from the class `JMessageBox` shows up it has pixel errors like this:
[image]

So my Question is, if there is a way to tell `java.awt` to use `WindowsClassicLook` similar to the settings I did with `java.swing`

Comment: `AWT` doesn't have a "look and feel" because it uses native components, therefore "looking and feeling" exactly like native components.

Comment: like Kayaman said you dont have look and feel in AWT. Can you edit your answer and post the snippet where you show the error dialog ? Or if you have a separate class which extends the JMessageBox post that please.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same problem I fixed it by using `java.swing.JPanel` instead of `java.awt.Panel`. I could just change the class in the variable Definition.